# R - data.table - group indexing approach for messy csv file

Tags: r, indexing, data.table

I am struggling in learning data.table however, I see it is exponentially faster. Therefore, here I am asking you the data.table approach to solve my problem.

The task I would like to accomplish through data.table is the following:
Suppose I have a 12Million .csv file structured similar to this:
NB: In the real file, each group has several hundred of records.

```
1;  
0.00;0.01;0.00  
2;  
-0.00;0.01;-0.02  
-0.00;0.01;-0.01  
0.00;0.00;0.01  
3;  
0.00;0.01;0.00  
0.01;0.01;-0.00   
4;  
0.00;0.01;0.00   
-0.00;0.01;-0.02    
5;  
0.00;0.01;0.00  
0.01;0.01;-0.00
```

The integer represent the ID while the records are observations belonging to that index. The answer is a solution that generate the following:

```
Var_A <- c(0.00, -0.00, -0.00, 0.00,0.01,0.00,0.01,-0.00,0.00,0.01) 
Var_B <- c(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01)  
Var_C <- c(0.00, -0.02, -0.01,0.00,-0.00,0.00,-0.00,-0.02,0.00,-0.00)   
ID <- c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3,4,4,5,5) 
solution_df <- data.frame(Var_A, Var_B, Var_C, ID)
```

Hoping the question was clear and I supplied you the sample data, I wait for your help :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can read the dataset using `readLines`, then with `str_count` create a logical vector based on the number of `;`, and then create the 'ID' by cumulative sum of the logical vector.  Then subset the data with logical vector, read with `read.table` and `cbind` with the 'ID'

```
library(stringr)
i1 <- str_count(lines, ";")==1
cbind(ID = cumsum(i1)[!i1], read.table(text=lines[!i1], sep=";"))
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines(textConnection(
"1;
0.00;0.01;0.00
2;
-0.00;0.01;-0.02
-0.00;0.01;-0.01
0.00;0.00;0.01
3;
0.00;0.01;0.00
0.01;0.01;-0.00
4;
0.00;0.01;0.00
0.01;0.01;-0.00
-0.00;0.01;-0.02
5;
0.00;0.01;0.00
0.01;0.01;-0.00")) 

#Or read from the file
lines <- readLines('file.csv')
```

Comment: thank you for your fast reply it is pretty cool! However, I probably did not explain my self correctly because this was not the methodology I need to solve the real problem